# Nested Dictionaries to Compile Testing Data

Tags: excel, vba, dictionary

I have the data set below, where each row constitues a test:

| date | Tech |
| --- | --- |
| 2/12/23 | Tim |
| 2/12/23 | Jane |
| 2/12/23 | Jane |
| 2/14/23 | Jane |

I am trying to build a report that tells how many tests each Tech conducted on each day.

The output should look like this

| date | Tech | # of Tests |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2/12/23 | Tim | 1 |
| 2/12/23 | Jane | 2 |
| 2/14/23 | Jane | 1 |

I am trying to use nested dictionaries, but feel like I am a) using them incorrectly or b) potentially just over thinking this. Here is what I have tried:

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub btnTestTracker_Click()

'DELERATIONS
Dim datarows As Long
Dim rngResults As Range
Dim dicdate As Object
Dim dictester As Object
Dim arrData As Variant
Dim arrTester() As Variant
Dim arrDate() As Variant
Dim idxRow As Long
Dim ky1, ky2 As Variant
Dim lastrow As Integer

Dim data As Worksheet
Set data = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data Transfer")

'GET NUMBER OF ROWS TO SEARCH
datarows = data.UsedRange.Rows.Count

'BUILD DATA SET
arrData = data.Range("a6:co" & datarows)

Set dictester = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Set dicdate = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

For idxRow = 1 To UBound(arrData, 1)
    ky1 = arrData(idxRow, 18)
    ky2 = arrData(idxRow, 20)
    
    If dicdate.Exists(ky1) Then
        
        arrDate = dicdate(ky1) ' SELECT DATE ARRAY FOR KY1
        
        If dictester.Exists(ky2) Then
            arrTester = dictester(ky2) ' SELECT TESTER ARRAY FOR KY2
            arrTester(0) = arrTester(0) + 1 'ADD TEST FOR KY2
            arrDate(1) = dictester(ky2) 'ADD TESTER + COUNT TO DATE DICT
        Else
            arrTester = Array(1) 'CREATE TESTER ARRAY FOR KY2
            arrDate(1) = dictester(ky2) 'ADD TESTER + COUNT TO DATE DICT
        End If
        
    Else
        If dictester.Exists(ky2) Then
            arrTester = dictester(ky2) ' SELECT TESTER ARRAY FOR KY2
            arrTester(0) = arrTester(0) + 1 'ADD TEST FOR KY2
        Else
            arrTester = Array(1) 'CREATE TESTER ARRAY FOR KY2
        End If
          arrDate = Array(1, dictester(ky2)) 'CREATE DATE ARRAY FOR KY1
        
    End If
    
    dictester(ky2) = arrTester
    dicdate(ky1) = arrDate
    
Next idxRow

'RECORD RESULTS
lastrow = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Test Tracker").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row
Set rngResults = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Test Tracker").Range("a" & lastrow + 1)

For Each ky1 In dicdate.Keys
    rngResults.Offset(, 0) = ky1
    For Each dictester In dicdate.Keys
        rngResults.Offset(, 1) = ky2
        rngResults.Offset(, 2) = dictester(ky2)(0)
        Set rngResults = rngResults.Offset(1)
    Next dictester
    Set rngResults = rngResults.Offset(1)
Next ky1
End Sub
```

When I run this, I get the following results:

| Date | Tester | # of Tests |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2/12/2023 | Tim | 1 |
|  | Jane | 3 |
|  |  |  |
| 2/14/2023 | Tim | 1 |
|  | Jane | 3 |

Any help is appreciated! I am also open to other or better methods to get this done. In the end, the data set will be fairly large.

Thanks!

Comment: You can use one dictionary and a composite key of `Date+Tester` (eg) "2/12/23|Tim"

Comment: Thanks @TimWilliams! This worked exactly how I needed it to. Looks like I was overthinking for sure in this case.

Answer (score 0):

### Create a Unique List Based on Two Columns

```
=LET(Data1,'Data Transfer'!R6:R20,Data2,'Data Transfer'!T6:T20,
    Delimiter,"|!|",Conc,Data1&Delimiter&Data2,uConc,UNIQUE(Conc),
    Counts,BYROW(Conc,LAMBDA(cRow,SUM(--(Conc=cRow)))),
    Stacked,HSTACK(Data1,Data2,Counts),rIndexes,XMATCH(uConc,Conc),
INDEX(Stacked,rIndexes,SEQUENCE(,COLUMNS(Stacked))))
```

[image]

```vb
Private Sub btnTestTracker_Click()
    CompileTestData
End Sub

Sub CompileTestData()
    
    Const SRC_NAME As String = "Data Transfer"
    Const SRC_FIRST_ROW As Long = 6
    Const DATE_COL As String = "R"
    Const TECH_COL As String = "T"
    Const KEY_DELIMITER As String = "|!|"
    Const DST_NAME As String = "Test Tracker"
    Const DST_COLUMNS_COUNT As Long = 3 ' fixed
    Const DST_COLUMN As String = "A"
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Sheets(SRC_NAME)
    
    Dim srg As Range, srCount As Long
    With sws.UsedRange
        srCount = .Rows.Count + .Row - SRC_FIRST_ROW
        Set srg = .Rows(SRC_FIRST_ROW).Resize(srCount)
    End With
    
    Dim sdData(), stData()
    
    With srg.EntireRow
        sdData = .Columns(DATE_COL).Value
        stData = .Columns(TECH_COL).Value
    End With
    
    Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
    
    Dim rKey, r As Long
    For r = 1 To srCount
        rKey = CStr(sdData(r, 1)) & KEY_DELIMITER & CStr(stData(r, 1))
        dict(rKey) = dict(rKey) + 1
    Next r
    If dict.Count = 0 Then Exit Sub
    
    Erase sdData
    Erase stData
    r = 0
    
    Dim drCount As Long: drCount = dict.Count
    Dim dData(): ReDim dData(1 To drCount, 1 To DST_COLUMNS_COUNT)
    Dim dLen As Long: dLen = Len(KEY_DELIMITER)
    
    Dim dPos As Long
    
    For Each rKey In dict.Keys
        r = r + 1
        dPos = InStr(rKey, KEY_DELIMITER)
        dData(r, 1) = CDate(Left(rKey, dPos - 1))
        dData(r, 2) = Right(rKey, Len(rKey) - dPos - dLen + 1)
        dData(r, 3) = dict(rKey)
    Next rKey
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Sheets(DST_NAME)
    Dim dfCell As Range
    Set dfCell = dws.Cells(dws.Rows.Count, DST_COLUMN).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = dfCell.Resize(drCount, DST_COLUMNS_COUNT)
    
    drg.Value = dData
    
    MsgBox "Test data compiled.", vbInformation

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

[image: Only with formulas]

[image: formulas]

this example use only formulas to create the report (LIST=Sheet3!$D$3:$D$10)

Answer (score 0):

Another way, maybe use COUNTIFS formula.

Before running the sub:
[image]

after running the sub: 
[image]

```
Sub test()
Dim sh As Worksheet: Dim rg As Range
Dim a As String: Dim b As String
Dim c As String: Dim d As String

Set sh = Sheets("Sheet1") 'change as needed
Set rg = sh.Range("A2", sh.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)) 'change as needed

With rg
    a = .Columns(1).Address
    b = .Cells(1, 1).Address(0, 0)
    c = .Columns(2).Address
    d = .Cells(1, 2).Address(0, 0)
    .Columns(1).Offset(0, 2).Value = "=countifs(" & a & "," & b & "," & c & "," & d & ")"
    .Columns(1).Offset(0, 2).Value = .Columns(1).Offset(0, 2).Value
    .Cells(1, 3).Offset(-1, 0).Value = "TEST"
End With

With sh
    .UsedRange.Copy Destination:=.Range("E1")
    .Range("E1").CurrentRegion.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2, 3), Header:=xlYes
    .Columns(3).ClearContents
End With

End Sub
```

Basically the sub just create a COUNTIFS formula in column C, then remove duplicate in the table.

The code give result without destroying the original data by copying the data to cell E1 then remove duplicate value.

To destroy the original data (no copy to cell E1), remove the `with sh - end with` block and use this line `sh.UsedRange.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2, 3), Header:=xlYes`